# Help required to solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To Solve: $\displaystyle \left [1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2\right]^{3/2}=a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

My Attempt: Take $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=p$

Now we have: $\displaystyle \left [1+p^2\right]^{3/2}=a\frac{dp}{dx}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dp}{\left (1+p^2\right)^{3/2}}=adx$

Cant take $\displaystyle 1+p^2=t$ as there is no p in the numerator. How do I go ahead?

Comment: What I would do is use $y'' =p\frac{dp}{dy}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write
$$\int\frac{dp}{(1+p^2)^{\frac32}}=\frac{p}{(1+p^2)^{\frac12}}.$$
(To see this, make the change of variables $p=\tan t$ in the initial integral).

Now it remains to solve for $p$ the equation$^*$
$$\frac{p}{(1+p^2)^{\frac12}}=\frac{x-x_0}{a}\qquad \Longrightarrow\qquad
p=\pm \frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{a^2-(x-x_0)^2}},$$
and integrate:
$$y(x)=\pm \int \frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{a^2-(x-x_0)^2}}dx=\mp \sqrt{a^2-(x-x_0)^2}+C.$$

---

$^*$ In your question $a$ incorrectly appears in the numerator instead of the denominator.

Comment: If I use $p=\tan t$, I have $\displaystyle \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1+\tan^2t)}}=\frac{dt}{\sec t}=\cos t dt=\frac{dx}{a}$. Its just getting more convoluted..

Comment: @user148176 I use the trigonometric substitution only to explain the first formula ($\int \cos t\, dt=\sin t= \frac{\tan t}{\sqrt{ 1+\tan^2 t}}$).